# Я хочу загрузить в бота список товаров с yml файла. Это возможно или нет?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, yml

У меня есть yml файл, и я хочу чтобы этот yml файл был подключен к моему боту, который в свою очередь будет выгружать эти файлы на телеграм канал. Это возможно? Если да, то куда вообще смотреть? И да, бота я делаю на Python

Comment: День добрый. Покажите, что у вас уже сделано.

Comment: Добрый, мой прокол. У меня нету пока что бота. Но я не знаю с чего даже начать. Есть задача, чтобы бот выгружал посты на канал в который он подключен. Но как внести в него базу того что надо выгружать - я не знаю. Даже как начать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Довольно абстрактный вопрос. Если вы разрабатываете скрипт бота для телеграмма, вы должны иметь сервер, где будет лежать скрипт, обрабатывающий запросы и ответы бота. В данном скрипте должен присутствовать функционал, считывающий информации из файла формата YAML, что да, конечно возможно через python. Cмотрите документацию по обработка информации из yaml-файлов [Работа с файлами в формате YAML](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/17_serialization/3_yaml.html).
Если же файлы в формате YAML будут просто загружаться в телеграмм-канал, то вам так же необходимо, что бы этот список файлов находился на сервере бота, и функционал, выгружающий эти файлы в скрипте самого бота. Например [так](https://habr.com/ru/post/348234/).